# Who is this man in Black Adder?

Tags: character, blackadder

In Episode 2 of the first season of [The Black Adder](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0084988/)?

[image: Still of man in a cage]

Comment: Role or actor? Or both?

Comment: He looks like the same man who played Og in Time Bandits (Mike Edmonds), but there is no credit listed under his name so it's probably not and the actor in your snapshot looks a bit younger (at the time this was filmed). 15 minutes on google turned up nothing. He is forever un-credited it seems.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the [pilot](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a5NWNHS3eM4) for the series, the pet was originally a dog in the cage:

[image]

According to *[The True History of the Blackadder: The Unadulterated Tale of the Creation of a Comedy Legend](http://books.google.com/books?id=x9C6eIHrKE8C&printsec=frontcover&dq=blackadder&hl=en&sa=X&ei=snTiUNr5FOTS2gWm2IGgAQ&ved=0CEMQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=dwarf&f=false)* (p. 107), the pilot was remade into the episode you cite. "Perhaps as a response to *The Young Ones*' surreal dimensions," the jokes were more outlandish in the series than the pilot, "the dog which Edmund kept in a cage in the pilot had now become his pet dwarf, for instance." You can watch the pilot in three parts on YouTube. Edmund in the pilot is more like the Edmund of the later Blackadder series rather than the doltish fellow we see in the first season.

Answer (score 6):

He is not named, but is supposed to be Edmund's *pet* dwarf. One of the prevalent legends about the dark ages is that some noblemen kept dwarfs in cages as pets to amuse themselves with. Whether  this is historically true or not is not something I can comment on though.